# DbSet Add method does not support inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4.3, dbcontext

I have the following POCO classes:

```
Public Class CompetitionSubscription
    Public Property ID As Long
    Public Overridable Property CompetitionID As Long
    Public Overridable Property CompetitionPlayerID As Long
    Public Property CompetitionStrength As Short?
    Public Property StrengthWithinSection As Short?
End Class

<NotMapped()>
Public Class FullCompetitionSubscription
    Inherits CompetitionSubscription

    Public Property Competition As Competition
    Public Property CompetitionPlayer As CompetitionPlayer

End Class
```

And a DbContext of just one table like this:

```
Public Class CompetitionSubscriptionsDB
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property CompetitionSubscriptions As DbSet(Of CompetitionSubscription)

End Class
```

I have written a unit test like this:

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub AddSubscriptionToDatabase()

     Using db = New CompetitionSubscriptionsDB
         Dim subscription = New FullCompetitionSubscription With
                          {.CompetitionID = 1,
                           .CompetitionPlayerID = 1,
                           .CompetitionStrength = 2,
                           .StrengthWithinSection = 12}
         db.CompetitionSubscriptions.Add(DirectCast(subscription, CompetitionSubscription))
         db.SaveChanges()
     End Using

 End Sub
```

This fails with the folllowing error (translated from Dutch so probably not the exact message): 
*No Metadata found for EntityType CompetitionSubscriptionsLib.FullCompetitionSubscription*.

As the `FullCompetitionSubscription` class is adorned with the `<NotMapped>` attribute I can understand the error message, but the point of the `DirectCast` was to "sell" the `FullCompetitionSubscription` as a base `CompetitionSubscription` to the `DbContext` (If I change the type of `subscription` to `CompetitionSubscription` the test passes).

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: This is a runtime error?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin it is part of the exception message that is thrown on running the test.

Comment: Why don't you try the DirectCast() on a previous line (assignment statement of CompetitionSubscription type), then you can use some reflection on the result.

Comment: I don't think that `DirectCast` changes the *runtime type*, but EF checks the runtime type to find the metadata and you can't pass in an object of a runtime type that isn't mapped. You either need to create a `CompetitionSubscription` object, not a `FullCompetitionSubscription` object, or you must provide a conversion operator which really creates a new object of the base type (and copies the property values). (I believe you'd have to use `CType` then to perform the custom conversion, but I'm not sure.)